# overlaying an image button with another image while selected

Tags: java, android, selecteditem, android-imagebutton

My ImageButton contains an Image of a drawing with a transparent area around. I have another Image of a rectangular (which has as well transparent areas), which I want to lay over the Image of the Image Button, so both are visible, as long as the button is selected.

This is the XML-Code for the Button:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonNormal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_1"
        tools:clickable="true" />
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try for floating custom buttons available on website (Android Arsenal). Floating Buttons have a property of getting overlayed.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to **overlay** an `imageview` over your `imagebutton`, just add them in a `relativelayout` (stack them on top of each other). for example,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/buttonNormal"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:onClick="normal"
        android:src="@drawable/first_image"
        tools:clickable="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/overlay_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now inorder to show the **overlay** image only when the button is pressed, just make the imageview(overlay) as `android:visibility="gone"`  by default and then make it **visible** when the `imagebutton` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into "selector" for android where you can define which drawable to show in different states of the button such as pressed etc.